# How to populate a NSTableView on a button click in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

I have got a CellBased NSTableView. I need to populate it on Button Click. I have written the code for populating the table implementing NSTableViewDataSource protocol. I have used an Array as Data Source.

The code is as below

```
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        let numberOfRows:Int = dataArray.count
        return numberOfRows
    }



     func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
}
```

But everything is getting loaded when I start the application. I want the data to get loaded on a Button Click like an IBACtion

```
@IBAction func findButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the delegate via interface builder, or elsewhere, set it in your button:

```
@IBAction func findButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your UITableView.dataSource to nil. Then when you are ready (button click) call tableView.dataSource = self. You might also have to call tableView.reloadData().

Haven't tested this but should in theory work.